# Javascript not correctly displaying nth-child(odd) pattern

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Trying to create a continuous list using multiple languages: **PHP**,**JavaScript**,**CSS**. However, as seen in the image, once the JS script gets called, it doesn't follow the continuous striped design of the list. I am using nth-child(odd) to create this design pattern, but no matter where I place the JS script it continues to behave incorrectly. Why is the JS script not continuing the pattern, and how could I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

[image: list of items]

**PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Assignment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="card">
    <ul id="item-list">
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) { ?>
            <li><?php echo "php " . $i; ?></li>
        <?php } ?>

        <script src="list_v2.js"></script>

        <li>CSS 1</li>
        <li>CSS 2</li>
        <li>CSS 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var ul = document.getElementById("item-list");
for(let i=1; i<4; i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "JavaScript " + i;
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #111;
}

li {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #808080;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ece2e1;
}
```

Comment: It's a little odd to run JS inline like this before the entire document has finished loading. I'd wait until the entire DOM is loaded, then begin trying to inject these elements. Not sure that'll solve the problem necessarily, but I think it'll be way easier to debug. Secondly, it's sort of odd to inject some content in PHP and some content using JS (you already have this content, it seems to be static, why not use PHP server side?). This makes me think some [important context is missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal reproduction (it has nothing to do with PHP):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #111;
}

li {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #808080;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ece2e1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="item-list">
  <li>PHP 1</li>
  <li>PHP 2</li>
  <li>PHP 3</li>
  <script>
  var ul = document.getElementById("item-list");
  for(let i=1; i<4; i++){
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = "JavaScript " + i;
      ul.appendChild(li);
  } 
  </script>
  <li>CSS 1</li>
  <li>CSS 2</li>
  <li>CSS 3</li>
</ul>
```

As I mentioned in a comment, it's unsafe to be inlining a JS script that manipulates an incomplete DOM element like this. Usually, you wait until the DOM is completely loaded, then run JS that might interact with the DOM.

You can use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to inject these elements into the proper position in the list after the DOM has finished loading, which doesn't bork the CSS rendering engine:

```js
const ul = document.getElementById("item-list");

for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = "JavaScript " + i;
  ul.insertBefore(li, ul.children[ul.children.length-3]);
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #111;
}

li {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #808080;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ece2e1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="item-list">
  <li>PHP 1</li>
  <li>PHP 2</li>
  <li>PHP 3</li>
  <li>CSS 1</li>
  <li>CSS 2</li>
  <li>CSS 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oddly, my list turned out different than yours. The code fixed the js, but now the last element of the js is the same color as the first element of the css list (both white).

Comment: Hmm! Did you move the JS script all the way to the bottom of the HTML page instead of including it in the list? You can do that in PHP but not in JS. Can you edit your post to show a [mcve] of the updated code? If PHP isn't a contributing factor to the bug, please omit it so you can show a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that makes it easy to see the problem in action. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `script` tag between list tags. And this should insert elements after all code executed.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("item-list");
for(let i=1; i<4; i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "JavaScript " + i;
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[ul.childNodes.length-3]);
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #111;
}

li {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #808080;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ece2e1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Assignment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="card">
    <ul id="item-list">
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) { ?>
            <li><?php echo "php " . $i; ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <li>CSS 1</li>
        <li>CSS 2</li>
        <li>CSS 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="list_v2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you are using **:nth-child**, this always includes all children irrespective of element type. Either try using **:nth-of-type** or never include other elements in children like other suggeted.
for more details refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
[image]

```css
.second span:nth-child(2n+1),
.third span:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="second">
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <script></script>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="third">
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <script></script>
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span!</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span!</span>
</div>
```